# Working with CPU intensive application

Tags: java, performance

I'm developing some Java EE application running on wildfly, which doesn't have much I/O. The results from I/O calls are heavily cached, so if doing some performance testing I can assume its CPU bounded

There is lot of math and some large array sortings (ca. 100000 entries) tasks. While the entries in array are POJOS

Allmost all of the work in single request is splitted into 500 tasks and done in a threadpool, which is sized to the number of CPU's.

Testing the application with a few users shows CPU utilization at 50-60%. I would expect it to be 90-100%

What might be the reason of low CPU utilization and what would be general advices for developing this kind of application to achieve maximum performance.

Comment: There's only one way to know: Profile your app and see what it's doing.

Comment: I did profiling and it showed the pool is constantly processing tasks

Comment: Profiling with what?  You get more than that from a profiler.

Comment: Can you identify the actual methods where the most cpu cycles are being spent? You should focus on that in order to gain the most performance.

Comment: I would split in more threads for CPU (increasing the thread pool).This java processing is sharing CPU (50/50) with other SO processes anyway.

Comment: With VisualVM. Looked at the threads and where the time is spent. All I can see is that the pool is busy and other threads are either waiting for new input requests (wildfly ones) or waiting the pool is done with the work. Well, it's my interpretation....

Comment: It just means that the load you generate is not sufficient to consume 90-100% of the CPU. Generate more load/review you test-cases to make sure your tests are hitting the heaviest branches of code.

Comment: @bashnesnos single requests takes about 300ms of computation. The question is, how to leverage all CPU power to make request processing faster. As I said, there is no I/O involved, so I'd expect all CPU's were busy at 90-100%

Comment: As @RaphaelMoita suggested - increase your thread pool, till you have CPU available and there is a speed-up. If you're on Intel CPU with Hyper-Threading you could do more threads than actual hardware CPUs, though the performance gain mostly depends on the load. In your case it will likely work since the data needed for both threads could fit into CPU cache.